# Is it possible for P to have degree less than 2n?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $P\in\mathbb{R}[x, y]$ be a polynomial such that there are exactly $n$ pairs $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $P(x, y)=0$.  Is it possible for $P$ to have degree less than $2n$?

Comment: Yes. Factor n into rs, and pick interesting polynomials P and Q with r and s real roots.  Use P(x)^2 + Q(y)^2 to get your n pairs at cost max (2r , 2s) <= n for composite n.

Comment: There are also versions for n a large prime that allow you to reduce the degree to slightly below n.  I leave that to you.